# I have a program that opens websites, and I set my default browser to google chrome, but it still uses Internet Explorer

Tags: python, google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser, python-webbrowser

This is what I have so far. Do I need to change anything to make webbrowser package use Google Chrome?

```
import webbrowser
web = input('What website would you like to open? i.e. pbskids.org')
webbrowser.open(web)
```

Comment: Read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) for details about how to specify which browser to open.

Comment: @Ruvee: the proper package tag is [tag:python-webbrowser]. Also, this question has at least a [hundred existing duplicates going as far back as 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+webbrowser+chrome), and should be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Usually, this is just an issue with your default browser. If you navigate to your Windows settings page, you can change the default browser to another installed web browser, in your case, Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps in your Python Application to open URL in Chrome Browser.
Register the browser type name using `webbrowser. register()` . Also provide the browser executable file path.
Get the controller object for the browser using `webbrowser. get()` and Open URL using `open()`. More details [Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://pythonexamples.org/python-open-url-in-chrome-browser/&ved=2ahUKEwjNoeu-mMXuAhUWQH0KHQy3BxEQFjACegQIAhAF&usg=AOvVaw2t6z3KpZhSg8SdOk14Meh_&ampcf=1)

Here is an example;

```
import webbrowser

url = 'https://pythonexamples.org'
webbrowser.register('chrome',
    None,
    webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser("C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe"))
webbrowser.get('chrome').open(url)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try setting the default browser as IE and then change it back to Chrome again?

Check the preferences of your programming app (Eg. PyCharm, Jupyter etc.)